# Initilize method in node module

Tags: node.js, module, initialization

in my understanding node modules are initialized when required for the first time. I would like to make some initialization code optional. Could I do something like this:

myModule.js:

```
module.exports.init=function(){
  this.foo = 'initialized';
};
```

To achieve this:

```
var myModule = require('./myModule');
myModule.foo === undefined; //true
myModule.init();
myModule.foo === 'initialized'; // true
```

Or is there a possibility of modules getting reloaded (and thus, in this case, uninitialized)?

Thanks for answers!

M

**Clarification:**
I do not want to reload the module. I want the module to remain uninitialized until some part of my application does so explicitly. The question is, does node ever reload cached modules so that, in the example above, *foo* will be undefined even though *init* has been called somewhere?

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit more? Would I be correct in assuming that you want to reload a module? If that is the case you could just assign another variable to the one in the requeire statement and then require it again

Comment: @Jasch1: I updated the question.